# Dijkstra's algorithm in Memgraph

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb, opencypher

I'm trying to run Dijkstra's algorithm in Memgraph on a dataset containing nodes with different properties, one of them being `Euro` and with different relationships, one of them being `:MarriedTo`.

My goal is to find the weighted shortest path between nodes based on the value of the `Euro` node property, traversing only across `MarriedTo` relationships and return the result as  path nodes. This is the query I've come up with:

```
MATCH path=(n {id: 0})-[:MarriedTo *WSHORTEST (r, n)]-(m {id: 9})
UNWIND (nodes(path)) AS node
RETURN node.id;
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Query failed: Function 'WSHORTEST' doesn't exist.
```

and I'm not sure how to fix it